# I change some text inside draggable node, then i drag this node in another container and the old value is back

Tags: javascript, dojo, javascript-framework, drag-and-drop, dojo-dnd

I have a dojo.dnd container (UL tag). inside of it i have an  tag (in LI tag), i change the value of this INPUT in browser and then i drag this LI to another container. After dropping i see the old value in my INPUT field. Could you help me not to lose a new value in input field

thanks

BEFORE DRAGGING, AFTER VALUE CHANGING
[image: befour dragging, after value changing]

AFTER DROPING
[image]

Comment: its not a native `<input>` is it? screenie is a nice demonstration and goes for a thousand words in explaining issue but for a solution you'd need to post some code

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that the space is breaking your code. Is the data URL encoded? Try replacing the space with "%20" and see if you still get the error.